# Problem with checking a subarray for a value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been facing this problem for some time and I have next to no ideas how it solve it.

```
import './OverflowModal.scss';

import { OverflowModeContext } from '@/stores';
import { OverflowContext } from '@/types';
import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { OverflowOption } from '@/components';
import { evenChutes, oddChutes } from '@/helper/chuteNumberCompare';

export interface OverflowModalProps {
  show: boolean;
  setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  currentChute: string;
  oddOptions: string[][];
  evenOptions: string[][];
}

export function OverflowModal({ show, setState, currentChute, oddOptions, evenOptions }: OverflowModalProps) {
  const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const { chuteOverflow } = useContext<OverflowContext>(OverflowModeContext)
  let overflowChuteIndex = 0
  let previousChute = "0"
  console.log(oddOptions)

  // const chosenOptions = Number(currentChute) % 2 === 0 ? evenOptions : oddOptions
  const chosenOptions = oddOptions

  for (let i = 0; i < chosenOptions.length; i++) {
    console.log(currentChute)
    console.log(chosenOptions[i])
    if (chosenOptions[i].includes(currentChute)) {
      console.log("Has chute:", currentChute)
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      modalRef.current?.classList.add("overflow-modal-visible")
    } else {
      modalRef.current?.classList.remove("overflow-modal-visible")
    }
  }, [show])

  return (
    <div ref={modalRef} className="overflow-modal-wrapper">
      <div className='overflow-modal'>
        <div className='overflow-selection'>
          {Object.keys(chuteOverflow).map(chuteName => {
            return (chuteName === currentChute) ? (
              <div key={overflowChuteIndex++} className='overflow-set-wrapper'>
                <p className='setting-title'>Setting overflow for chute {chuteName}</p>
                <div className='options-wrapper'>
                  {/* {optionsToGenerate?.map((chuteId) => {
                    console.log(chuteId)
                    if (evenChutes(chuteId, previousChute, chuteName)) {
                      const overflowOption = <OverflowOption overflowOption={previousChute} currentChute={chuteId} />
                      previousChute = chuteId
                      return overflowOption
                    }
                    if (oddChutes(chuteId, previousChute, chuteName)) {
                      const overflowOption = <OverflowOption overflowOption={previousChute} currentChute={chuteId} />
                      previousChute = chuteId
                      return overflowOption
                    }
                    previousChute = chuteId
                    return null
                  })
                  } */}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
              :
              ""
          })}
        </div>
        <div className='buttons-wrapper'>
          <button className='overflow-close-button ripple' onClick={() => setState(false)}>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I want to do is check if `currentChute` is in a array that I have stored as an array.

```json
[
  [
    "1",
    "3",
    "5",
    "7",
    "9"
  ],
  [
    "11",
    "13",
    "15",
    "17",
    "19"
  ],
  [
    "21",
    "23",
    "25",
    "27",
    "29"
  ],
  [
    "31",
    "33",
    "35",
    "37",
    "39"
  ]
]
```

The array looks like this.
As an example whenever I try to check if 39 is in a subarray, when it gets to the array it appears in, that value just disappears.

[image: Screen shot of my console.logs]

And as you can see above 39 is in the array but not when I want to check.

I tried passing `"39"` in the `chosenOptions[i].includes(currentChute)` instead of currentChute and it works fine. But the prop never works.
And yes I am aware some thing are commented out. This is just the latest sample I have of this issue I am facing.

If more context is needed I can add. Sadly I can't put this into StackBlitz or CodeSandbox as I am using something, that creates too many issues for me to solve when trying to import this into a sandbox.

**EDIT:**
I have done some digging, but nothing has changed. Everything should work, so I have no idea what I am missing. It doesn't seem like I am missing anything, but I can't judge that as the console.logs show all the right information before I begin to look for currentChute.

Comment: const chosenOptions = oddOptions

  for (let i = 0; i < chosenOptions.length; i++) {
    console.log(currentChute)
    console.log(chosenOptions[i])
    if (chosenOptions[i].includes(currentChute)) {
      console.log("Has chute:", currentChute)
    }
  }

is this the logic to find currentChute?

Comment: @SarthakGupta Yes as currentChute is something that I pass down from a parent component. And I need to find the array that currentChute is in.

I have posted the array with subarrays in my post.

I originally used .find with a .includes inside and that also didn't work.

Comment: console.log(chosenOptions[i]) --> when you are logging this , does this contain the proper subarray with your chuite value ? and can you please once log typeof(currentChute)

Comment: @SarthakGupta if you look at the picture at the bottom, you will see what I get in the console.

Essentially the behaviour right now is:
Whenever 39 is currentChute and it checks for the array it is supposed to be in, it disappears/gets removed. And as you can see the array I also posted, the last array contains it, but when it gets to it, it is gone. 

But as I also console.log(oddOptions) at the start, it shows that it is there.

Comment: i think the issue is with the type of currentChuite and the elements inside your subarray . Can you please make sure they are same. try (chosenOptions[i].includes(String(currentChute)))

Comment: This didn't change anything at all.
currentChute is string and the elements in the subarray are all string as well.